# How to pass ' -search.maxUniqueTimeseriesi' flag to in victoriametrics?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-command, victoriametrics

As the database got bigger we faced this problem:

> the number or matching unique timeseries exceeds 300000; either narrow down the search or increase -search.maxUniqueTimeseries

The [Docs](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md#how-to-export-data-in-native-format) show a solution:

> On large databases you may experience problems with limit on unique
> timeseries (default value is 300000). In this case you need to adjust
> -search.maxUniqueTimeseries parameter:
>
> count unique timeseries in database

> wget -O- -q 'http://your_victoriametrics_instance:8428/api/v1/series/count' | jq '.data[0]'

> relaunch victoriametrics with search.maxUniqueTimeseries more than value from previous command

The **docker-compose** file looks now something like this:

> victoria-metrics: 
> image:
> dns_search:
> environment:
> command:
> - '--search.maxUniqueTimeseries=1000000'

this still doesn't solve the problem.

How can I pass the flag in docker compose correctly?

## UPDATE

The image I was using didn't take flags from **docker-compose.yml** to consideration. This was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> this still doesn't solve the problem.

Do you mean the flag isn't set? Can you check the following metric `flag{name="search.maxUniqueTimeseries"` on VicotriaMetrics /metrics page? Or via the following command:

```
curl http://<vm-address>:8428/metrics | grep maxUniqueTimeseries
```